# How does a Gaussian process scale with the dimensionality of inputs and outputs?

Tags: gaussian-process

Let us say we are fitting a GP on a multidimensional dataset.

```
N - Number of data points  [O(N^3), which is known]
D - Dimensionality of each input 
M - Dimensionality of each output
```

Can someone tell how GP scales with D and M? It will be a huge help if you can provide references.